# I have to try auto populate in Quote object , Quote object related to opportunity

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking

I have created a list button in related list and pass all value in custom button url, we need to update lookup field when before save this quote.

Shown below.

```
    /a0j/e?CF00N50000007sHbA={!Opportunity.Name}
    &CF00NA0000005JzZX_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
    &00N50000007sHaI={!Opportunity.Account}
    &00N50000007sHaI_lkid={!Opportunity.AccountId}
    &00N50000007sHbR={!Opportunity.Billing_Contact_contactroles__c}
    &00N50000007sHbR_lkid={!Opportunity.Billing_Contact_contactroles__c}  
&00N2C000000UF0f={!Opportunity.OwnerId}&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}
```

Can anyone explain the mistake in my code.

Comment: Are you trying to set these field on Quote object?

Answer (score 0):

To auto populate the fields in the Quote object, you need to start off like this:

```
/0Q0/e?retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}&oppid={!Opportunity.Id}&....
```